# Angular: how to reset form elements that map to different data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My angular app has > 1 forms on a page. Each form can be saved or reset. The fields on each form don't necessarily map to its own data object.

For example I have two pieces of data that **must** be gotten and saved separately. Let's call the json chunks, `a` and `b`.

HTML:

```
<form>
<input type="text" ng-model="a.foo"/>
<input type="text" ng-model="b.bar"/>
</form

<form>
<input type="text" ng-model="b.bar[0].baz"/>
<input type="text" ng-model="a.boo"/>
</form
```

If the first form were mapped to just `a` and the second to `b` it would be a simple matter of resetting the data. But I don't want to reset all the `a` or `b` data for all forms on the page. I just want to reset the specific data fields for the inputs represented on a particular form.

My current logic *mostly* works. On cancel I get the elements in the form, get their ng-model attributes and dynamically reset properties on `a` and `b` depending on the ng-model string value. This seems "dirty" and plus it doesn't work for some ng-model attributes which use the $index special variable because the attr value isn't parsed by angular when doing .attr(). What's the best solution for this? Different models for each form that map back to the original data?

Answer (score 0):

- Make a deep copy of the object you are editing when opening the form and edit it ( angular.extend)
- when save just use your save logic
- on cancel you will need to do nothing

e g

```
 .controller('myctrl', function($scope, dataService) { 
    $scope.data = angular.extend( {}, dataService.get())

    $scope.save = function ( ) {

      dataService.set($scope.data)
    }

})
```

Comment: I'm not sure you understand my question, though I may have not worded it clearly. I need to reset just selected fields in a form, not all of them. What's the pattern for that in angular?

Comment: how you define which fields to reset and which not ?

Comment: are they modal ? ie you can edit only one form at a time ?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this before, but you can try having something like below:

```
<form>
<input type="text" ng-model="form1.element1" ng-change="a.foo=form1.element1"/>
<input type="text" ng-model="form1.element2" ng-change="b.bar=form1.element2"/>
</form>

<form>
<input type="text" ng-model="form2.element1" ng-change="b.bar[0].baz=form2.element1"/>
<input type="text" ng-model="form2.element2" ng-change="a.boo=form2.element2"/>
</form>
```

to have an easy reference to your form-specific elements. And then for resetting, you can simply reset the `form1` or `form2` objects with initial values using `angular.copy()`.

One thing you may need to watch with this approach is, once you enter some values and reset although on the `form1` or `form2` will be reset, there may still be values in `a` and `b` objects, you might want to handle that (disable submit for e.g.)